# Leaflet+Vue+Vuetify / Leaflet map hide vuetify popup dialog

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, vuetify.js

On my Vuetify + Lealflet project the map hides all popup dialogs and I don't know why. I use Vue2Leaflet library. I am a beginner with web development.  Here is a pic of the problem:

[image]

```
               <l-map
                                :center="center"
                                :zoom="zoom"
                                @click.right="mapRclicked"
                                ref="map"
                                style="height: 50vh; width: 50vh"
                >
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is a clash of z-index ranges. Vuetify uses z-index ranges 0-10 while leaflet uses the range 100-1100. Fortunately, the z-index of a child element is relative to the z-index of their parent.

I advice you to give `l-map` a z-index of 0 like this.

```
<l-map
  :center="center"
  :zoom="zoom"
  @click.right="mapRclicked"
  ref="map"
  style="z-index: 0; height: 50vh; width: 50vh"
>
```

This will automatically bring your component in line with all of Vuetify z-indexes. In contrast, @bgsuello workaround requires that you modify the z-index of every Vuetify component that may conflict with the map, including other dialogs, menus, animations, tabs, toolbars, snackbars...

Comment: Remember that the map element also needs to have positioning for the z-index to have any effect
e.g. `position: relative`

Answer (score 5):

Edit: This is an outdated answer.

#### see @Javier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54635107/4539748) below as pointed out by @ondrejsv on comment.

> It does not work anymore at least in `Vuetify 2.1.9` and `Vue 2.6.x`. The solution by Javier seems to work.

---

Increase the `z-index` style property of your dialog.

```
<v-dialog style="z-index:9999;"
... rest of your code ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much bgsuello :) I had to set my map z-index too.

Comment: It does not work anymore at least in Vuetify 2.1.9 and Vue 2.6.x. The solution by Javier seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

I find it quite practical to wrap the map in an image, like this

```
<v-img
  height="100%"
  width="100%">
    <l-map>
    ... 
    </l-map>
</v-img>
```

This way there is no need to do anything with the z-index.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Vue2.x + Vuetify + Vue2leaflet.

I tried many things and finally what worked for me was to cover the  with a . My code reads as :

```
<v-lazy>
  <v-img>
    <l-map>
     .... rest of the code
    </l-map>
  </v-img>
</v-lazy>
```

This takes inputs on v-lazy from https://medium.com/@elralimi.lamia/leaflet-vuejs-vuetify-map-not-showing-well-in-a-modal-with-grey-parts-9a5d551ea472. v-img was suggested by geomuc in the above response.

Other options that I tried but failed were: this.map.invalidateSize(); , this.map.remove();, this.$nextTick(() => {...}, z-index.